# Whack a mole Python OOP

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to create an object orientated program in Python for a whack-a-mole program.

I want to keep this simple where there are just a hammer and a mole and when the hammer turtle makes contact with the mole turtle.

I have created 4 classes one for Game which is the superclass, one for sprite which inherits from Turtle and one each for hammer and mole which both inherit from Sprite.

What I am asking is how to instantiate the mole and hammer turtles I have made use of inheritance but want to minimize the amount of methods I am using 
The code I have used is

```
import random
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
wn.addshape("moleSmall.gif")
wn.addshape("Mole.gif")
wn.addshape("Hammer.gif")
turtle.setup(800, 600)

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.score=0
        self.pointsDisplay=Points()

    def update_score(self,x,y):
        self.score = self.score + 2
        print("Score:", self.score)
        self.callDisplayScore()        
    def decrease_score(self,x,y):
        self.score = self.score -1
        print("Score: ", self.score)
        self.callDisplayScore()
    def callDisplayScore(self): 
        score = self.score
class Sprite(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
        self.x=0
        self.y=0
        crash =False
        self.crash=crash
    def randomMove(self):        
        leftbound = -self.wn.window_width()/2
        rightbound = self.wn.window_width()/2
        topbound = self.wn.window_height()/2
        bottombound = -self.wn.window_height()/2
        rand_x = random.randint(leftbound , rightbound)
        rand_y = random.randint(bottombound, topbound) 
        self.mole.setpos(rand_x,rand_y)
    def collisionCheck(self,turtle1, turtle2):
        self.crash = False
        turtle1X = turtle1.xcor()
        turtle1Y = turtle1.ycor()
        turtle2X = turtle2.xcor()
        turtle2Y = turtle2.ycor()
        turtle1Pos = (int(turtle1X), int(turtle1Y))
        turtle2Pos = (int(turtle2X), int(turtle2Y))
        if turtle1Pos == turtle2Pos or turtle1X < turtle2X - 50 and \
            turtle1Y > turtle2Y - 50 and  turtle1X < turtle2X - 50 and\
            turtle1Y > turtle2Y + 50:
            self.crash = True
        return self.crash
class Mole(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.mole.pu()
        self.mole.shape("moleSmall.gif")
        self.x= self.mole.xcor()
        self.y = self.mole.ycor()
        self.randomMove()
class Hammer(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.counter = 0
        self.hammer.penup()
        self.hammer.shape("Hammer.gif")
        self.hammer.penup()
        leftbound = -self.wn.window_width()/2
        rightbound = self.wn.window_width()/2
        topbound = self.wn.window_height()/2
        bottombound = -self.wn.window_height()/2
        rand_x = random.randint(leftbound , rightbound)
        rand_y = random.randint(bottombound, topbound)
        self.hammer.setpos(rand_x,rand_y) 
    def HammerMove(self):
        self.hammer.pu()
        self.hammer.clear()
        self.wn.onscreenclick(self.hammer.goto)
        while self.collisionCheck(self.mole, self.hammer) == False:
            self.randomMove()
            if self.collisionCheck(self.mole, self.hammer) == True:
                self.score = self.score + 1
                print(self.score)
```

Comment: I think this would be a better question on Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: Actually this code looks incomplete - i.e. not-working, and thus would not be [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for CR...

Comment: ...hack a mole.

Comment: If you want help with this you should reduce that code to a [mcve] that we can run. But anyway, there are a few problems with that code. What's `Points()`? What do you expect `Game.callDisplayScore` to do? The code refers to various undefined attributes like `self.mole` and `self.hammer`.